# Elasticsearch - Default token in Analyzer if emitted tokens are empty

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, querydsl

The requirement is - when firing a Search query on Elasticsearch index, we have one big Elastic Query DSL query built to run a a search on the index.

For one of the property field, we have applied a custom analyzer.

One of the Filter used in the analyzer is a synonym translator, which produces one of the 4 expected tokens based on input strings/tokens.

> IF nothing matches, is there a way to test if emitted tokens are null - only then set "typeA" as default output token ?

If the input text had no matching synonym to map, then I get only empty token array. But I need to place this in a must[]  block (i.e. this CustomTypeAnalyzer is applied on a property in a query which is used in a must query block.

So it cannot be empty, I need a default token to be emited by the Analyzer, if my choice of default token is 'typeA', then I need my analyzer to emit the default token only if the CustomTranlator did not yeild any tokens.

How can I do it ?

*I tried conditional filter, but that too seems to operate only on input tokens only.*

**I basically need to be able to test if emitted tokens are null.**

I cannot run multiple queries (analyzer api first then search api etc is not possible/feasible), my query builder will run and fire one search query on the index.

> So I want my Custom Analyzer itself to be conditionally able to emit a default token ***if the emitted tokens were to be null***.

Regards,
Sumanth

**My custom analyzer is like this**

"MyCustomTypeAnalyzer" : {
"filter" : [
"EngStopWordsRemover",
"lowercase",
"EngStemmer",
"CustomTranslator",
"SpaceTokenRemover",
"unique"
],
"tokenizer" : "standard"
}

**The custom translator is something like this**

"CustomTranslator" : {
"type" : "synonym",
"synonyms" : [
"volunt,voluntari,chip,regist => typeA",
"program,event,particip,partak,regist => typeB",
"contribut,donat,donor,give,provid,sponsor,fund,raise,money,support => typeC",
"enlist,associat,enrol,join,member,membership,regist => typeD",
]
}

1. For an input string like "I would like to spend some time teaching kids" - then I get empty tokens.
2. For an input string "I would like to join a teaching activity" emits the token "**typeD**"

I want to be able to test the emitted tokens size of the analyzer and emit a default token **typeA**  conditionally, but this must be built into the analyzer itself

Answer (score 0):

your question isn't clear. I hope my solution is fitted for you

Mapping with your `synonym` filter and my conditional `pattern` filter to replace unsynonymed tokens with the default token 'typeA'

```
PUT /token_replace
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "replacing_token_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "typead_synonym_filter",
                        "conditional_replacer_filter"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "typead_synonym_filter": {
                    "type": "synonym",
                    "synonyms": [
                        "volunt,voluntari,chip,regist => typeA",
                        "program,event,particip,partak,regist => typeB",
                        "contribut,donat,donor,give,provid,sponsor,fund,raise,money,support => typeC",
                        "enlist,associat,enrol,join,member,membership,regist => typeD"
                    ]
                },
                "conditional_replacer_filter": {
                    "type": "pattern_replace",
                    "pattern": "(.++)(?<!\\btype[A-D])",
                    "replacement": "typeA"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Synonym pair for typeA is meaningless. All unreplaced tokens are replaced with 'typeA'

Your first text

```
GET /token_replace/_analyze?filter_path=tokens.token
{
    "analyzer": "replacing_token_analyzer",
    "text": "I would like to spend some time teaching kids"
}
```

Response

```
{
    "tokens" : [
        {
            "token" : "typeA"
        },
        {
            "token" : "typeA"
        },
        {
            "token" : "typeA"
        },
        {
            "token" : "typeA"
        },
        {
            "token" : "typeA"
        },
        {
            "token" : "typeA"
        },
        {
            "token" : "typeA"
        },
        {
            "token" : "typeA"
        },
        {
            "token" : "typeA"
        }
    ]
}
```

Your second text

```
GET /token_replace/_analyze?filter_path=tokens.token
{
    "analyzer": "replacing_token_analyzer",
    "text": "I would like to join a teaching activity"
}
```

Response

```
{
    "tokens" : [
        {
            "token" : "typeA"
        },
        {
            "token" : "typeA"
        },
        {
            "token" : "typeA"
        },
        {
            "token" : "typeA"
        },
        {
            "token" : "typeD"
        },
        {
            "token" : "typeA"
        },
        {
            "token" : "typeA"
        },
        {
            "token" : "typeA"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: "I would like to join a teaching activity" should have returned typeD as token isn't it ?   Nevertheless thanks for this suggestion to sequence two filters and try replacement, I will try this approach and get back.   I would put a uniuqe filter too to remove duplicate tokens.  I had tired a token remover filter that places deault but it was acting on input tokens and not emitted tokens, but within analyzer itself, wiill try this analysis approach you suggested  which acts on analyzer output.

Comment: The fifth token for "I would like to join a teaching activity" is typeD. See accurately. But  your question is still unclear.  Is index result for "I would like to join a teaching activity" only typeD or my response?